# Shorthand IF within Laravel HTML Form

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-facade

I have a form input set up using the HTML facade:

```
{!! Form::text('name', NULL, ['class' => 'form-control ($errors->has("name") ? " has-error" : "")', 'placeholder' => 'Enter your name'] ) !!}
```

As you can I have put the $error->has inside the class but it is just printing the if statement as I know it would.

Is there anyway I can do what I am trying but keep on using the Form facade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put the if statement outside the single quotes:

```
{!! Form::text('name', NULL, ['class' => 'form-control'.($errors->has("name") ? " has-error" : "").'', 'placeholder' => 'Enter your name'] ) !!}
```